# Separate numbers and words in a string

Tags: stata

I have a string variable in Stata, that contains entries such as:

```
110xyz 43 abc 
110xyz 44 abc
111 xyz 56 abc
```

The key is that sometimes the first set of numbers (anything from 1 to 5 digits long) is not followed by a space before the next word begins (and that can be anything from 1 to 50 letters long). Is there a neat way to insert a blank to separate number and word? (`110 xyz` would be the desired result in the above example) I tried`regexr()`, but that doesn't help.

Comment: "doesn't help" is opaque as an error report. Always say exactly what you tried and why it isn't satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What went wrong with `regexr()`? It seems exactly the tool to use, so perhaps it's regular expressions you're having trouble with.

My Stata syntax might be a little off, but try something like this:

```
gen string = "110xyz 43 abc"
gen number = regexs(1) if regexm(string, "^([0-9]+) *([a-zA-Z].*)")
gen remain = regexs(2) if regexm(string, "^([0-9]+) *([a-zA-Z].*)")
gen fixed  = number + " " + remain
```

This can be simplified, but I'm starting you off with what I think has the highest probability of working, *e.g.* guaranteed match, because I don't know what kind of null value results if `regexm()` didn't match.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. You were right, just me having trouble with regular expressions.

Comment: Simplified into a single line, as Andrew suggested: `replace string = regexr(s,"^[0-9]*",regexs(1)+" ") if regexm(s,"^([0-9]*)[^0-9 ]")`

Answer (score 2):

`moss` from SSC offers a convenience wrapper for Stata's regular expression functions. Demonstration:

```
clear 
input str16 test 
"110xyz 43 abc" 
"110xyz 44 abc"
"111 xyz 56 abc" 
end 
ssc inst moss
help moss 
moss test, match("([0-9]+)") regex pre(num) 
moss test, match("([a-z]+)") regex pre(word)
list test *match* 

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     |           test   nummat~1   nummat~2   wordma~1   wordma~2 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  110xyz 43 abc        110         43        xyz        abc |
  2. |  110xyz 44 abc        110         44        xyz        abc |
  3. | 111 xyz 56 abc        111         56        xyz        abc |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```